# .NET Winform - Multiline listview (see Screenshot)

Tags: .net, winforms, listview

How can i create this sort of listview in .NET application , are there any free components on the market that could do that 'out of the box' ? Many thanks
[image: Screenshow]

Answer (score 1):

The Telerik winforms controls appear to have a listbox that supports the above appearance:

[image]

> The DropDownList and ListControl are
>   also capable of displaying images,
>   text, multiline text, and rich text by
>   using standard HTML tags, such as < i >,
>   < b >, and < u >.

http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/dropdown-and-list.aspx#appearance

Answer (score 0):

[Better ListView Express](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview-express) allows you to use multiple lines using *Tile* view (each line is a sub-item) and arbitrary image sizes:

[image]

The [full version](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) is more powerful and allows multi-line text even in *Details* view.

Answer (score 0):

[ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) is very powerful, fast, and ts open source
[image]

The project comes with a demo you can play with to achieve your aim